# dropdown closing if click on tab

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

when clicking on tabs inside the dropdown is closing, and then when clicking again on drop down tab is changed. using wordpress, porto theme. code is bellow. what is wrong?

```
<div class="dropdown messages-menu">
  
  <a  href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="tmarketst"><i  class="porto-icon-user-2" ></i></span>  My Profile
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
      <li class="active"><a data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Log in </a></li>
      <li><a data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Register</a></li>
      
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home"><?php echo do_shortcode("[wc_login_form_mmy]"); ?> </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile"><?php echo do_shortcode("[wc_reg_form_mmy]"); ?></div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
$('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event){
//The event won't be propagated to the document NODE and 
// therefore events delegated to document won't be fired
   event.stopPropagation();
 });

 $('.dropdown-menu li').on('click', function(event){
   //The event won't be propagated to the document NODE and 
   // therefore events delegated to document won't be fired
   event.stopPropagation();
 });
   
 $('.dropdown-menu > ul > li > a').on('click', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).tab('show')
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I did not fully understood your question. Here is a working drop-down: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_button

PS: I would only use css... (integrating LOTS of media-queries)
I could show you a responsive drop-down which works the problem is that it only fits for my website...

Comment: There is a tabs inside drop down.active tab is log in.  While clicking on tab register, drop down is closing. have to click again on drop down to enter data in register.

Comment: #dropdown:hover {display: inline-block} this should maintain drop down